# create new vue instance in Vue 3 use require js

Tags: requirejs, vuejs3

I have vue instance which is vue 2. The code is below. It seems add axios to prototype then return new vue.

```
(function () {
  define('newVueInstance', ['axios'], (axios) => {
    let newVueInstance = {
      VERSION: '1.0',
    };
    const Vue = require('vue').default;

    const axios_instance = axios.create({

    });

    Vue.prototype.$axios = axios_instance;
    newVueInstance = new Vue();

    return newVueInstance;
  });
}());
```

I want to turn it into vue 3. The code is below. `require('vue').default` is undefined.

````
(function () {
  define('newVueInstance', ['axios'], (axios) => {
    const newVueInstance = {
      VERSION: '1.0',
    };
    // const Vue = require('vue').default; // undefined
    const Vue = require('vue');
    const axios_instance = axios.create({

    });
    const app = Vue.createApp();
    console.log('********', require('vue'));
    console.log('Vue', Vue);
    app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;

    return require('vue');

    // return newVueInstance;
  });
}());
```.
It doesn't work.
````

Comment: What does `require('vue')` return?

Comment: return a vue instance

Comment: So maybe you should just get rid of `.default`?

Answer (score 0):

First issue comes with Vue 3 is not exactly APM compatible which means the browser side require.js will not work.

Second is Vue 3 does not export a default. One needs to create a `createApp` instance.